# Android TV Emulater is Blank. How can I see apps like Google Play Store and others?

Tags: android, android-tv

I have started new Android TV Emulator. But it shows nothing except settings and search icon. I am unable to open even Google Play to add more apps.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to reCreate Tv emulator

Comment: Or show your Tv Emulator properties

Comment: But I already tried same thing by creating more than 5 emulators. Problem is I can see Networks, Search icon and behind the scene nice wallpaper.

Comment: I'll suggest you to use GenyMotion Emulator its fast and easy to use

Comment: @HassanUsman, But GenyMotion emulator supports Android TV emulation ?

Comment: @HassanUsman, I tried with GenyMotion, but it doesn't display TV device.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84917/discussion-between-rajdip-patel-and-hassan-usman).

Comment: The AndroidTV emulator comes with a pared-down PlayStore-like app called katniss. Note that it does not allow purchases but does permit some searching. You can start it from the command-line thusly: adb -e shell am start -n com.google.android.katniss/.search.SearchActivity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Play is not included in emulator images (whether for TV or other devices) - the emulators only contain Android apps, not any of the Google apps.

(Whilst Android may be a free OS, what you receive on your actual phone is not - many of the key parts of that package are provided by Google, and are proprietary).

You can install your app to the TV emulator by using ADB.

Comment: Then how to install Google Play Store App on emulator ? Is this possible ? How phone manufacturers get google's play store and installs in phone image ?

Comment: Phone manufacturers get to install Google Play Store (and any of the other Google apps such as Gmail) by reaching an agreement with Google to do so - which presumably involves them paying money to Google.  Android device manufacturers who choose not to pay Google, such as Nokia and Amazon, do not include the Google apps, and have to offer their own app store.